# Node detecting termination

Tags: node.js

Is it possible for a node script to detect if it was terminate from "external" (p.e.: kill) or internal by a script error?

To be more precise:
The first case should't not be a main process that "observe" its children, or a additional script that "looks" if the main script is still running.

2nd case: without putting everything in try-except-blocks. I m looking for a function that is called when an error would stop the script.

Comment: Read documentation http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var exceptionOccured = false;

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
    exceptionOccured = true;
    process.exit();
});

process.on('exit', function(code) {
    if(exceptionOccured) console.log('Exception occured');
    else console.log('Kill signal received');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when I kill the process myself with Ctrl+C

Comment: Add `process.on('SIGINT', function(){process.exit()})` to also handle termination by `Ctrl+C`